# Filler-words in spoken Italian

Tags: word-usage, idioms

In casual, spoken English, there are certain "filler-words" which are very common, but don't really add much to the actual meaning of the sentence. For example: "like, you know..., look....".

The same thing seems to exist in Italian. I want to a) confirm that this true, b) find out what the common filler-words are.

For example, are these common filler-words?:

- guarda (look)
- dai (come on now)
- sai (you know)

What other Italian words or expressions would be in this category?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there are filler words. Those you mentioned actually can be used meaningfully ("*dai*" is an exhortation for example).

Aside from those you mentioned, other examples may be:

- cioè
- mah
- mmm (though not exactly a word)
- eh

and many others. An example dialogue using all of them:

```
A) Sai, ho visto Luca in giro con l'auto nuova.
B) Eh? Strano.
A) Perché?
B) Eh, guarda, non so se posso parlartene... cioè...
A) Dai...
B) Mmm, è che pensavo gli avessero tolto la patente... mah...
```

Comment: (I'm on a foreign keyboard most of the time, so I don't have the accented e letter at hand. Both cioe' and perche' actually are with accent, not apostrophe!)

Comment: Accents are now fixed.

Comment: I am a devotee of the High Church of Nitpicking.

Comment: Don't forget "Boh"!

Answer (score 5):

- **Mah** is used to convey uncertainty, as in: *"Hai visto Marco ultimamente?" "Mah, sarà preso dallo studio"* (I don't know where he is, but I think he might be busy studying) or *"Cosa ne diresti se andassimo a correre domani?" "Mah, sono un po' stanco in questi giorni.."* (I'm not interested in going jogging because I am tired. I want to be polite and not openly say "I don't want to come with you").
- **Insomma / cioè** / are used to better explain a point or to get to the real point of the conversation: *"Maria ha un po' di problemi a casa e al lavoro, e esce meno con gli amici. Insomma, è sparita dalla circolazione"* or *"Ti richiamo dopo. Cioè...quando avrò finito di studiare e mettere in ordine la casa"*.
- **Allora** is kind of the equivalent of "so" in English. Used to start a conversation, to bring up a new topic or to call for attention: *"Allora, come è andata in vacanza? Rcconta!"* or *"Allora, bambini, venite qui e mettetevi seduti" in cerchio".*

NB "cioè" can sound like "c'è" in spoken language. I don't know if it is a northern Italy thing or not.

Answer (score 2):

Insomma..., ecco una lista:

- allora
- cioè
- dai
- eh
- guarda
- insomma
- mah
- mmm
- quindi
- senti
- sai

Ho aggiunto 'quindi' e 'senti'.

Comment: Anche "niente"... ho appena sentito una persona al telefono che lo diceva ogni due frasi: "Niente, adesso sto arrivando..."

Answer (score 0):

I'll add the filler-words that I use the most, and which I also happen to find rather annoying (trying to get rid of this bad habit, with little success!):

- *Tipo* or *tipo che* (the equivalent of *like*)
- *Praticamente* or *in pratica*